# How do I bundle packages with node installer?

Tags: node.js, installation, npm

I'm running an educational project where kids needs to install node and some packages themselves before they start. I want to make it super simple for them to do themselves. Right now it's a matter of:

1. Download and install Node as a `.msi` or `.pkg`
2. Run some `npm install` command in a terminal which is less friendly.

Is there any way to bundle some packages with node and create one simple download that will just work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know that [node webkit](https://github.com/rogerwang/node-webkit) is able to do what you need, and even more; if you opt on it, you will probably find other useful features for your purpose.